# Can I have iTunes 11 revert to filtering by word instead of phrase?

Tags: itunes

The filter/search in previous iTunes worked on a word-based matching system.  If each of the words matched anywhere in the song info (title, artist, genre, etc) then a song was returned.  It appears that the new default in iTunes 11 is for it to be a phrase-based match.

This breaks searching as far as I'm concerned.  For example, there's no longer any way to search by artist and genre.  If I have an artist with a bunch of different genres and I want to listen to a subset I'm not unable to do this.  Example:  "sufjan christmas" used to bring back all my Sufjan Stevens Christmas music.  Now it brings back nothing because nothing has the phrase "sufjan christmas" in it.

Is there a way to revert to the old method of filtering?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to revert to the old functionality by clicking on the magnifying glass in the search box and unchecking "search entire library".  This had the side effect of speeding up the searching greatly as well as filtering in place instead of taking me to a different screen when I clicked on the search result.